# Display Name of Files In Progress Bar While Syncing

Tags: android, progress-bar

My Application Syncs data from server when it gets launched for first time. Now i want to show progress bar during this syncing process and i want to display the name of files as well which are getting synced from the server.
Please help me if anyone have any idea about how to that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default way to achieve this.

However, you can use any layout that allows overlaying of views (such as `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`), to put your `TextView` above of `ProgressBar`. Then, you should update the value of `TextView` according to names of files that you read (probably, inside a loop).

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/download_progress
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/download_file_name
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_grvity="center"
    >
</RelativeLayout>
```

And configure colors, so they would be contrast enough.

Comment: do you have any idea about how to update the value of TextView according to names of files that i am reading from Server. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: actually we are retreiving data from the server and saving it into the sqlite database for the user convenience.so by hitting api for the server. we retrieve the data and read it using  bufferedReader and InputStreamReader.

Comment: Do you get all the files using one stream? how and when do you split it into files?

Comment: no i have created different methods and in every method i am calling a different server api . and reading them using inputstreamreader in every method

Comment: Am I right, that you know name of downloaded file in any method? Then you can show this file in a text view. But concrete way of doing it depends on your app architecture (where you make network calls, for example) and there is no single answer to your question.  A general pattern - before making network call you should set TextView with needed text.